# Table border issues in ie

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

Hey guys ,

I having this kind of issue in IE ,I m using bootstrap3 , the td bottom borders are going out of it ,as seen in image the bottom-border is extending out of the background color

Comment: When asking IE-related questions, it's always helpful to specify the IE version(s) that you're tesing with and also the browser mode that it's using to display the page.

Comment: What is your HTML (and CSS) code?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following parameter to your table:

```
<table cellpadding="0">
```

**Update**
Only cellpadding i mean.